# Placing "functionalized index" in R (MATlab code to R)

Tags: r, matlab, bayesian, inference

I am trying to translate some code from matlab into R.

If necessary: The full matlab code can be viewed here, STARTIN LINE 46, "Dynamical perception": https://github.com/rssmith33/Active-Inference-Tutorial-Scripts/blob/main/Pencil_and_paper_exercise_solutions.m

BACKGROUND if necessary: pencil and paper example for active inference (similar predictive coding, it is essentially approx. Bayes inference...): https://psyarxiv.com/b4jm6/   at page 135

---

MY QUESTION:

I am pretty new to this, but I was able to fully replicate the math (essentially approx Bayes) of the matlab script in R without doing a loop, now I want to replicate the loop.

In the matlab code it says:

```
>% observations = vectors!
o{1,1} = [1 0]';
o{1,2} = [0 0]';
o{2,1} = [1 0]';
o{2,2} = [1 0]';
```

In the matlab loop it e.g. says:

```
% likelihood
 lnAo = nat_log(A'*o{t,tau});
```

So the o{x,y} works as index for the upper o{x,y} vector, or in my case: t (i.e. timestep) and tau:

o{t,tau} where t = timestep {1,} or {2,} and tau is {,1} or {,2} of the upper o{ , }

For calculating the math WITHOUT a loop I used these so far:

```
# True observation at t-1
o11 = c(1, 0)   
o12 = c(0, 0)

# True observation at t-2
o21 = c(1, 0)       
o22= c(0, 1)   

# I used it for something like this, where I manually added the right o{x,y} to the formula.
st2all = ... ... +  ((log(t(A))%*%o22))
```

My guess I could either target the last character of my "o12" for tau and the second last for t (time) and define it some way, but how (and does it make sense)?

Or is there an elegant equivalent for this function in R somehow?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is something like the `cell` structure in Matlab

```
> o <- matrix(list(c(1, 0), c(0, 0), c(1, 0), c(1, 0)), 2, byrow = TRUE)

> o[[1, 1]]
[1] 1 0

> o[[1, 2]]
[1] 0 0

> o[[2, 1]]
[1] 1 0

> o[[2, 2]]
[1] 1 0
```

Comment: Actually you are right, it is a cell array, just assigned from outside. I will look if I find an answer for translating that into R. https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/add-cells-to-a-cell-array.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a way to return the value of `o` depending on the values of `t` and `tau`, so you can easily put this code into a loop? If so, you could define a function `o(t, tau)` that returns the values given in the Matlab example above.

**Note** that `t()` is the transpose function in R, so I'm using the variable name `timestep` instead of `t`. You *can* define a variable named `t` but then you won't be able to call the function, and it looks like you'll need to transpose matrices to transalte the rest of your Matlab code.

Here's a function `o(timestep, tau)` that gives the results you want:

```
o <- function(timestep,tau){
  # default response is c(1,0)
  result <- c(1,0)
  # response is c(0,0) iff t==1 and tau ==2
  if (timestep == 1 & tau == 2) result <- c(0,0)
  
  return (result)
}
```

And here's a simplified example of two nested loops that will iterate over all combinations of 1 and 2 for `timestep` and `tau`, calling our function `o()` and doing some simple demonstration math:

```
# set up a starting value for demonstration
x <- c(1,1)

# loop over all values of 1 and 2 for t and tau
for(timestep in 1:2){
  for (tau in 1:2){

    # each iteration, call our function `o` and do some math
    x <- sqrt(x) + o(timestep,tau)
    
  }
}
```

The math in your loops will look different of course because you're doing more complicated stuff.

Comment: THANKS A LOT FO THE QUICK ANSWER! So the calculation roughly goes like this: one has a formula with "x+o{t,tau}" and the calculation is performed for every t and every tau. So it ends up doing this: calculating x+o{1,1} takes the result as new input for x and then caculates the formula again with new-x + o{1,2} and in timestep 2 it uses o{2,1} and o{2,2}. So the loop is supposed to know bei the values of {x,y} which vector it is supposed to use.

Comment: In response to what I think you're getting at, I've edited the answer to show how you can use this function in nested loops. Note that I've also changed the variable `t` to `timestep`, since `t()` is the matrix transpose function in R, and it looks like you'll need it to translate your matlab function.

Comment: Thanks alot! That should bring me forward!

Comment: Turns out it is this function in matlab, second example: https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/add-cells-to-a-cell-array.html

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out the rest via https://www.latecnosfera.com/2016/05/matlab-cell-arrays-equivalent-in-r.html

```
o <- vector("list", length = 2 * 2)
dim(o) <- c(2, 2)
o

o[[1, 1]] <- c(1, 0)
o[[1, 2]] <- c(0, 0)
o[[2, 1]] <- c(1, 0)
o[[2, 2]] <- c(0, 1)

# This worked so far and the loop shouldn't be too much of a problem now I hope. :)
st2all2 = ..... +  ((log(t(A)+nzlog)%*%o[[2,2]]))
```

Thanks for all the help!!